# pandas.read_sql_table producing table not found error

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to access my Oracle 11g(r2) Express Edition database via python.  I specifically want to create a pandas DataFrame from one of the tables, HISTORY_FULLNESS.  However, when I try to use the pandas.read_sql_table() function, it gives me a Table Not Found error.  In the code below I duplicate the query that the engine is executing, and it clearly has HISTORY_FULLNESS in the results.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

I have the following code (*** added to obfuscate ip and password):

```
### Imports ###
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cx_Oracle
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import sqlalchemy

# Open connection to Oracle Database
OpsDBengine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://OPSDBADMIN:***@***.***.***.***:1521/', echo=True)

connection = OpsDBengine.connect()
result = connection.execute("SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE nvl(tablespace_name, 'no tablespace') NOT IN ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX') AND OWNER = 'OPSDBADMIN' AND IOT_NAME IS NULL")
for row in result:
    print "tablename: ", row['table_name']


testDF = pd.read_sql_table(table_name = 'HISTORY_FULLNESS', con=OpsDBengine, schema='OPSDBADMIN', index_col = 'FULLNESSRECORDID')
```

The output is as follows:

```
2015-02-19 15:23:58,714 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT USER FROM DUAL
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT USER FROM DUAL
2015-02-19 15:23:58,716 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
2015-02-19 15:23:58,740 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60 CHAR)) AS anon_1 FROM DUAL
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60 CHAR)) AS anon_1 FROM DUAL
2015-02-19 15:23:58,740 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
2015-02-19 15:23:58,746 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS NVARCHAR2(60)) AS anon_1 FROM DUAL
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS NVARCHAR2(60)) AS anon_1 FROM DUAL
2015-02-19 15:23:58,749 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
2015-02-19 15:23:58,766 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE nvl(tablespace_name, 'no tablespace') NOT IN ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX') AND OWNER = 'OPSDBADMIN' AND IOT_NAME IS NULL
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE nvl(tablespace_name, 'no tablespace') NOT IN ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX') AND OWNER = 'OPSDBADMIN' AND IOT_NAME IS NULL
2015-02-19 15:23:58,766 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
tablename:  SAFETY_CASEFILE
tablename:  HTMLDB_PLAN_TABLE
tablename:  HISTORY_FULLNESS
tablename:  HR_EMPLOYEE_PHOTOS
tablename:  HR_MANAGER_DEPARTMENT_GROUPS
tablename:  DB_DEPARTMENT_GROUPS
tablename:  HR_MANAGER_DEPT_ASSIGNMENTS
tablename:  HR_MANAGER_SHIFT_ASSIGNMENTS
tablename:  HR_EMPLOYEE_ROLE
2015-02-19 15:23:58,825 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE nvl(tablespace_name, 'no tablespace') NOT IN ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX') AND OWNER = :owner AND IOT_NAME IS NULL
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE nvl(tablespace_name, 'no tablespace') NOT IN ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX') AND OWNER = :owner AND IOT_NAME IS NULL
2015-02-19 15:23:58,825 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'owner': u'OPSDBADMIN'}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'owner': u'OPSDBADMIN'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8f6c6d72ed22> in <module>()
     15 
     16 
---> 17 testDF = pd.read_sql_table(table_name = 'HISTORY_FULLNESS', con=OpsDBengine, schema='OPSDBADMIN', index_col = 'FULLNESSRECORDID')

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in read_sql_table(table_name, con, schema, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    334         meta.reflect(only=[table_name])
    335     except sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:
--> 336         raise ValueError("Table %s not found" % table_name)
    337 
    338     pandas_sql = SQLDatabase(con, meta=meta)

ValueError: Table HISTORY_FULLNESS not found
```

Comment: the following line DOES work: testDF = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM HISTORY_FULLNESS", con=OpsDBengine)

Answer (score 1):

Kinda old question, but could help others:

You could use 2 ways to do this:

1. testDF = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM HISTORY_FULLNESS", con=OpsDBengine)
2. output = con.execute("SELECT * FROM HISTORY_FULLNESS"); testDF = pd.DataFrame(outpt.fetchall());

Answer (score 1):

I realized I'm posting on a very old question but I ran into this same issue with oracle. Have you tried making the table name lower case? That's what worked for me.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11258

```
### Imports ###
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cx_Oracle
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import sqlalchemy

# Open connection to Oracle Database
OpsDBengine = 
sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://OPSDBADMIN:***@***.***.***.***:1521/', echo=True)

connection = OpsDBengine.connect()
result = connection.execute("SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE nvl(tablespace_name, 'no tablespace') NOT IN ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX') AND OWNER = 'OPSDBADMIN' AND IOT_NAME IS NULL")
for row in result:
print "tablename: ", row['table_name']


testDF = pd.read_sql_table(table_name = 'HISTORY_FULLNESS'.lower(), con=OpsDBengine, schema='OPSDBADMIN', index_col = 'FULLNESSRECORDID')
```